# changing NSButton CALayer hides its title

Tags: ios, calayer, nsbutton

I'm trying to change a button background by this way :

```
    [table[i][j] setAttributedTitle:attrString];
    [table[i][j] setTitle:@"-"];
    table[i][j].tag=i*10+j;
    table[i][j].frame = CGRectMake((i*30+40), (j*30+106), 30.0, 30.0);
    [self.mainView addSubview:table[i][j]];
    CALayer *buttonLayer = [CALayer layer];
    buttonLayer.contents=(id)[NSImage imageNamed:@"icaseinactiv"];
    [table[i][j] setWantsLayer:YES]; // view's backing store is using a Core Animation Layer
    [table[i][j] setLayer:buttonLayer];
```

However, once I apply the new layer, its title disappears (the title is still there when I remove the last line. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm pretty sure `NSButton` won't be using a layer by default, so it will be drawing using the normal `[NSView drawRect:]` method.  You then added a layer which covers this *canvas* and voilà, this is what happens.

In order to do what you want you will need to subclass `NSButtonCell` I reckon.

Comment: that sounds pretty accurate so how do I correct that ? How could I make the buttons title visible upon the new layer ?

Comment: @VincentMonteil No, you'll have to subclass `NSButtonCell` I reckon.